# Using the ls command to hide non-executable files

Tags: linux, grep, ls

I'm trying to have a command that will print only the non-executable files sorted by modification time in the current directory.

What I have so far is:

```
$ ls -lt | grep -i "...x......"
```

This is printing all of the files in the dir. Just starting to learn code, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go :

```
for file in *; do test -x "$file" || echo "$file"; done
```

Thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: When I run this it has no output. Is that for a specific file? Even after I ran "$touch file" it has no output.

Comment: The updated code worked perfect, thank you for your help.